# Firebase database pagination scrolling action

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, pagination

I'm following the tutorial:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#6

I was trying to achieve pagination, Here is what i have modified:

```
...
Query query = databaseRef.limitToLast(50);
...
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<FriendlyMessage> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<FriendlyMessage>()
                    .setQuery(query, parser)
                    .build();
...
```

Here is the scrolling code as tutorial as default:

```
mFirebaseAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new 
RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
   @Override
   public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
       super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
       int friendlyMessageCount = mFirebaseAdapter.getItemCount();
       int lastVisiblePosition =
              mLinearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
       // If the recycler view is initially being loaded or the 
       // user is at the bottom of the list, scroll to the bottom 
       // of the list to show the newly added message.
       if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 ||
               (positionStart >= (friendlyMessageCount - 1) &&
                       lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart - 1))) {
           mMessageRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(positionStart);
       }
   }
});

mMessageRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter);
```

Now the screen shows only 50 messages.

But it don't scroll to the bottom when new messages coming.It works fine before using query.

I want to know where should I start to modified.

Thank you.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42502024/get-the-data-from-the-firebase-in-limit-to-perform-pull-to-refresh-and-load-more) Start from lastItem when refreshing with `startAt(oldestPostId)`. Or, a complete solution for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44777989/firebase-infinite-scroll-list-view-load-10-items-on-scrolling/44796538#44796538

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท thanks for your comment, I have edited the question. I just found out that I need to deal with this problem before implementing the scroll up action.

Comment: **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741958/how-to-paginate-firestore-with-android)** is a recommended way in which you can paginate queries by combining query cursors with the limit() method. I also recommend you take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KdgKvLll07s)** for a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

From the swift side:

By changing the startKey, we can query the data from where we want(from the end of the database) and achieve the pagination by scrolling to the top of the screen.

```
if (startKey == nil){
        print("firebasetest_startkey: ",self.startKey)
        // for first grabbing data operation

        _refHandle = self.ref.child(channel_title).queryOrderedByKey().queryLimited(toLast: 30).observe(.value){(snapshot) in
            guard let children = snapshot.children.allObjects.first as? DataSnapshot else{return}
            if (snapshot.childrenCount > 0){
                for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
                    if(!(self.messageKeys.contains((child as AnyObject).key))){
                        self.messages.append(child)
                        self.messageKeys.append(child.key)
                        self.itemTable.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.messages.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
                    }
                }
                self.startKey = children.key
            }
        }
    }else if (dragdirection == 0 && startKey != nil){
        //going up
        // for all other grabbing data operation from the bottom of the database

        _refHandle = self.ref.child(channel_title).queryOrderedByKey().queryEnding(atValue: self.startKey).queryLimited(toLast: 10).observe(.value){(snapshot) in
            guard let children = snapshot.children.allObjects.first as? DataSnapshot else{return}
            if (snapshot.childrenCount > 0 ){
                for child in snapshot.children.reversed(){
                    if ((child as AnyObject).key != self.startKey &&
                        !(self.messageKeys.contains((child as AnyObject).key))){
                        self.messages.insert(child as! DataSnapshot, at:0)
                        self.messageKeys.append((child as AnyObject).key)
                        self.itemTable.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .fade)
                    }
                }
                self.startKey = children.key
            }
        }
    }
```