# Having Trouble Loading Earlier Messages in React-native GiftedChat Chat App with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-gifted-chat

I have been working on a chat app using Gifted-Chat and a Firebase RealTime database (and running it with Expo). At this point, the basic messaging works, but I am trying to enable to app to load earlier messages when the user scrolls up and hits the button that appears (I am aware of the GiftedChat prop for this). Unfortunately, I have been having trouble doing this and am a bit stumped.

There are two separate problems I have been running up against that I am aware of.

1. Clicking the loadEarlier button gives me an `undefined is not a function (near '...this.setState...'` runtime error (clearly, something is wrong with the skeleton function I put there).
2. The bigger issues is that I am still not clear on how to download the *n* number of messages before the oldest messages currently loaded. I have looked at [the GiftedChat example](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/blob/master/example/App.js) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42502024/get-the-data-from-the-firebase-in-limit-to-perform-pull-to-refresh-and-load-more) for help, but must confess that I am still lost (the best I can figure is that I need to sort the messages, possibly by timestamp, somehow get the right range, then parse them and prepend them to the messages array in state, but I cannot figure out how to do this, especially the later parts).

The relevant parts of the code for my chat screen are below, as is a screenshot of the structure of my firebase database. I would appreciate any help regarding both of these issues.

```
// Your run of the mill React-Native imports.
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
// Our custom components.
import { Input } from '../components/Input';
import { Button } from '../components/Button';
import { BotButton } from '../components/BotButton';
// Array of potential bot responses. Might be a fancy schmancy Markov
// chain like thing in the future.
import {botResponses} from '../Constants.js';
// Gifted-chat import. The library takes care of fun stuff like
// rendering message bubbles and having a message composer.
import { GiftedChat } from 'react-native-gifted-chat';
// To keep keyboard from covering up text input.
import { KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';
// Because keyboard avoiding behavior is platform specific.
import {Platform} from 'react-native';

console.disableYellowBox = true;

class Chat extends Component {
    state = {
        messages: [],
        isLoadingEarlier: false,
    };

    // Reference to where in Firebase DB messages will be stored.
    get ref() {
        return firebase.database().ref('messages');
    }

    onLoadEarlier() {
        this.setState((previousState) => {
          return {
            isLoadingEarlier: true,
          };
        });
        console.log(this.state.isLoadingEarlier)
        this.setState((previousState) => {
            return {
                isLoadingEarlier: false,
            };
        });
    }

    // Get last 20 messages, any incoming messages, and send them to parse.
    on = callback =>
        this.ref
          .limitToLast(20)
          .on('child_added', snapshot => callback(this.parse(snapshot)));
    parse = snapshot => {
        // Return whatever is associated with snapshot.
        const { timestamp: numberStamp, text, user } = snapshot.val();
        const { key: _id } = snapshot;
        // Convert timestamp to JS date object.
        const timestamp = new Date(numberStamp);
        // Create object for Gifted Chat. id is unique.
        const message = {
            _id,
            timestamp,
            text,
            user,
        };
        return message;
    };
    // To unsubscribe from database
    off() {
        this.ref.off();
    }

    // Helper function to get user UID.
    get uid() {
        return (firebase.auth().currentUser || {}).uid;
    }
    // Get timestamp for saving messages.
    get timestamp() {
        return firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
    }

    // Helper function that takes array of messages and prepares all of
    // them to be sent.
    send = messages => {
        for (let i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            const { text, user } = messages[i];
            const message = {
                text,
                user,
                timestamp: this.timestamp,
            };
            this.append(message);
        }
    };

    // Save message objects. Actually sends them to server.
    append = message => this.ref.push(message);

    // When we open the chat, start looking for messages.
    componentDidMount() {
        this.on(message =>
          this.setState(previousState => ({
              messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, message),
          }))
        );
    }
    get user() {
        // Return name and UID for GiftedChat to parse
        return {
            name: this.props.navigation.state.params.name,
            _id: this.uid,
        };
    }
    // Unsubscribe when we close the chat screen.
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.off();
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <View>
            <GiftedChat
                loadEarlier={true}
                onLoadEarlier={this.onLoadEarlier}
                isLoadingEarlier={this.state.isLoadingEarlier}
                messages={this.state.messages}
                onSend={this.send}
                user={this.user}
            />
         </View>
        );
    }

}
export default Chat;
```

[image: Screenshot of DB]

Answer (score 1):

For your first issue, you should declare your `onLoadEarlier` with `=>` function so as to get the current instance `this` i.e. your code should look like below:

```
onLoadEarlier = () => {
    this.setState((previousState) => {
      return {
        isLoadingEarlier: true,
      };
    }, () => {
       console.log(this.state.isLoadingEarlier)
       this.setState((previousState) => {
          return {
             isLoadingEarlier: false,
          };
       });
    }); 
}
```

Also, `setState` is asynchronous in nature, so you should rather depend on the second parameter of the `setState` i.e. the callback to ensure that the next lines of code execute synchronously.

Lastly, if you are using `class` syntax then you should declare the state in `constructor` like below:

```
class Chat extends Component {
   constructor (props) {
      super (props);
      state = {
         messages: [],
         isLoadingEarlier: false,
      };
   }
  ......

    onLoadEarlier = () => {
      this.setState((previousState) => {
        return {
          isLoadingEarlier: true,
        };
      }, () => {
         console.log(this.state.isLoadingEarlier)
         this.setState((previousState) => {
            return {
               isLoadingEarlier: false,
            };
         });
      }); 
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this all works. I am still pretty new to React-native (first project), so am wondering why I should declare state in the constructor?

Comment: [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) might help you understand how the class members are defined and declared.

Comment: Thank you, I did not realize how complex javascript is. After going through the page though, I am still confused as to why a constructor needs to be used to declare state, given that the code works for me after applying your first fixes without adding a constructor.

Comment: Sorry, never mind, I think that I finally mostly understand the whole binding thing. If you get a chance to look into how to load older messages though, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

For loading the last messages from firebase , I recommend using limitToLast function on your reference. You should afterwards order the results by date before calling append in gifted chat.

Comment: The trouble I was running into with that was figuring out how to avoid redownloading all of the messages that I already have. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, it should be the same with this question [How Firebase on and once differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55213044/how-firebase-on-and-once-differ)

You can using filter feature in Firebase for example using createdAt field to compare with last loaded message to load more.